# Get Caption text from several ToggleButtons if their value=True

Tags: excel, vba, userform, togglebutton, caption

I would like to ask for some help how to make this efficent.

My Userform has a bunch of togglebuttons which turns green if pressed and they all have unique Captions. Then i have a command button. My goal would be that when i press the commandbutton, i need it to take the Captions from every pressed/activated command button and past those caption text in the last empty row beneath each other.
So far what i have looks like this:
(I would really appraciate if you could suggest me any other more effective way to do this, if this one is is not)

Normal module:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    
    Set toggleButtonCollection = New Collection
    
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    Dim cToggleButton As clsToggleButton
    
 
     For Each ctrl In FinomMintak.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "ToggleButton" Then
            ctrl.BackColor = vbWhite
            Set cToggleButton = New clsToggleButton
            Set cToggleButton.toggleButton = ctrl
            toggleButtonCollection.Add cToggleButton
        End If
    Next ctrl

    Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Class module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents toggleButton As MSForms.toggleButton

Private Sub toggleButton_Click()
   
    With toggleButton
        If .Value = True Then
            .BackColor = vbGreen
        Else
            .BackColor = vbWhite
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Many thanks to everyone who takes the time with my problem.

I tried to implent the whole thing in the existing module class, also tried to create new one(probably did it wrong) but i could make it work so far. So i would like to ask a little push to the right direction.

Comment: Instead of FinomMintak.Controls try Me.Controls

Comment: ...inside a class module like a Userform or Worksheet you can use `Me` to refer to the object itself.